# How can this MySQL query return NULL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-variables

```
SET @last_nid=-1; 
SELECT vid,
     IF(@last_nid = nid, @last_status, 0) AS last_status,
     @last_status := status AS status,
     @last_nid := nid AS nid 
FROM node_field_revision 
ORDER BY vid;
```

`nid` and `vid` are both positive integers and `status` is either 0 or 1.

I am at a complete loss at how can `last_status` result in a `NULL` -- but it sure does.

MySQL manual says:

> If expr1 is TRUE (expr1 <> 0 and expr1 <> NULL), IF() returns expr2. Otherwise, it returns expr3.

Well, at first iteration `@last_nid` can not be equal to `nid` because one is negative and the other is positive. Therefore, 0 is returned. Yes, `@last_status` is NULL here but it can not be returned. Then it fills in `@last_status` with the value of `status` which is either 0 or 1.

In further iterations, `@last_status` will never be made NULL again.

And yet, an overwhelming majority of rows has NULL as its `@last_status` -- if I give `@last_status` an initial value then that doesn't happen but then again, this means my thinking and my query is bogus but why/how?

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and make a [mre]

Comment: This is actually a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/11589439/308851 , MySQL (obviously?) runs the calculations in the wrong order, forcing it with `CASE` works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subtracting the value from the last row using variable assignment in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589439/subtracting-the-value-from-the-last-row-using-variable-assignment-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You do not initialize `@last_status` variable so server assumes it is a constant of NULL.

Init ALL variables before the query execution, not only one of them, or do it in the query:

```
SELECT vid,
     IF(@last_nid = nid, @last_status, 0) AS last_status,
     @last_status := status AS status,
     @last_nid := nid AS nid 
FROM node_field_revision 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @last_nid:=-1, @last_status:=0) AS initialize_variables
ORDER BY vid;
```